# The singular and plural has been a major issue for me as a pro se first-timer

Tags: claims, claim-construction, dependent-claim

Nothing I have seen sounds right for my little invention, so I wonder what I'm missing. The invention needs at least one X somewhere on at least the first side of Y for the minimum invention to work. In the preferred embodiments, one or more additional X at particular locations and/or slope directions on Y adds value and narrows the claim. So the dependent claims need to say: at least one X on the second side of Y.  at least one X proximal to the distal end of Y.  at least one X proximal to the proximal end of Y.  at least one X to slope left.  at least one X to slope right. What is a good way to say this?

Comment: Something like.. A Y with integrated X suitable for bananas, comprising: a Y having a handle and a blade, the blade having a first side, a second side, a distal end, and a proximal end; and at least one X on the first side, wherein the at least one X is a delineation on the surface of the blade that depicts a guide mark, wherein the guide mark is constructed relative to the distal end.  2. The Y tool defined in claim 1, wherein the at least one X is on the second side.  3. The Y tool defined in claim 1, wherein the at least one X is located proximal to the blade distal end. 4., etc.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I am not sure if I understood you. 1. Whatever comprising: at least one X, the at least one X comprising a first X at location A. 2. ...wherein the at least one X further comprises a second X at location B. 3. ...wherein the at least one X further comprises a second X at location C. Am I getting it correctly? Does that answer your question?

Comment: the Europeist: How about this? Independent claim: Comprising Y with side A and B; and at least one X on location A. Dependent claims: The at least one X on location B. The at least one X on a more specific location on Y. The at least one X on another specific location on X. ....Question: does "The at least one" still mean "at least one" for each location area?

Comment: That is wrong in my opinion because then you have a same X in two different locations. You cannot use that definition to refer to one X in one place and another X in another place.

Comment: What if X is a special type of angle guide mark. The angle must be constructed relative to the distal end of the tool regardless of where it is on the tool and it must be on the surface. This type of tool has never had this type of guide mark before. One of these guide marks on the tool is enough for the tool to work in a novel way. The angle can be any angle between say 0° & 90°. a couple of different angles by the distal tip works better and a couple of angle marks by the handle workes better, do the same to the other side of the tool works better still. Two particular angles are best.

Comment: I am confused. What is the relevance of these angles in the question how to draft the claims? Can the same X be in two different locations simultaneous? If the answer is no, then simply relating "the at least one X" with two locations is not correct.

Comment: Yes, the same angle, such as 45° (or some other angle), can be in several places on the tool at once as long as the 45° angle is relative to the distal end of the tool. Each would be a separate guide mark. So there can be a total of say, four 45° angle guide marks on the tool and perhaps five 22.5° guide marks, as long as all the angle guide marks are indicative of angles relative to the distal end of the tool. Having the guide marks in several places makes the tool easier to use. Some locations are particularly helpful.

Comment: Can a common tool with a special guide mark be patented? The guide mark is special only because it is relative to a part of that particular tool. Can a preferred embodiment have additional guide marks that fulfill the same principle thereby making the tool even better? It seems so simple, but then when I write it in what I think is patent language it drives me crazy. I have the prototype, I have drawn it. It works great. I can not afford a lawyer. It's fun to learn. I don't plan on making much money if any. That's why I'm doing this Pro Se.

Comment: "Each would be a separate guide mark." My first comment then.

Comment: Thank you the Europeist. As I reread your first comment, I realize it has the answer. Sorry to be so obtuse.

Comment: No worries, I am glad it solved your question. I will post it as an answer then so that we can wrap up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draft it like this:

1. Device comprising: at least one X, the at least one X comprising a first X at location A.
2. Device according to claim 1, wherein the at least one X further comprises a second X at location B.
3. Device according to claim 1, wherein the at least one X further comprises a second X at location C.

Comment: I noted you said a second X at location C, would that not need to be a third X?

Comment: @ProSeHole If the dependent claim depends upon claim 1, then it is second X, if it depends upon claim 2 then it is third X. The number of Xs you have in each claim determines the numeral thereof. In this case, drafting the X of claim 3 as third X results in lack of clarity because there is no second X in the subject-matter of claim 3+claim 1.